# Error al ejecutar "yarn build" en una aplicación de Next Js y Typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js, nextjs, fs

Estoy intentando construir una aplicación de Nextjs y Typescript, solo que al querer ejecutar "$ yarn build", me aparece el siguiente error:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./lib/mdx.ts Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> '/Users/brandonurielgarciaramos/Sitios Web/imSoft/Nextjs/imsoft/lib'
>
> Import trace for requested module: ./lib/mdx.ts ./lib/index.ts
>
> Build failed because of webpack errors error Command failed with exit
> code 1.

Estoy utilizando el siguiente código:

```
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import matter from "gray-matter";
import { serialize } from "next-mdx-remote/serialize";

interface FrontMatter {
  [key: string]: any;
  slug: string;
}

const root = process.cwd();

export const getFiles = () => fs.readdirSync(path.join(root, "posts"));

export const getFileBySlug = async (slug: string) => {
  const mdxSource = fs.readFileSync(
    path.join(root, "posts", `${slug}.mdx`),
    "utf-8"
  );

  const { data, content } = await matter(mdxSource);
  const source = await serialize(content, {});

  return {
    source,
    frontMatter: {
      slug,
      ...data,
    },
  };
};

export const getAllFilesMetadata = () => {
  const files = getFiles();
  return files.reduce<FrontMatter[]>((allPosts, postSlug) => {
    const mdxSource = fs.readFileSync(
      path.join(root, "posts", postSlug),
      "utf-8"
    );
    const { data } = matter(mdxSource);

    return [{ ...data, slug: postSlug.replace(".mdx", "") }, ...allPosts];
  }, []);
};
```

y aquí es donde esta ubicado el archivo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba cambiando la importación a `import * as fs from "node:fs";`

Comment: No me funciono :/, me aparece todo esto: node:fs
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:fs" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.

Answer (score 1):

Al final pude responderlo de la siguiente manera:

```
interface FS {
  readdirSync(path: string): string[];
  readFileSync(path: string, encoding: string): string;
}

let fs: FS;
if (typeof window === "undefined") {
  fs = require("fs");
}
```

La verdad desconozco si es la forma más elegante o adecuada pero me sirvio, si me pudieran dar recomendaciones de como mejorar el código o algo así serán bien recibidas. :)

Answer (score 0):

Basándome en una [pregunta muy similar de StackOverflow (en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64926174/module-not-found-cant-resolve-fs-in-next-js-application):

Next.js es un framework que permite combinar rendering en el lado del servidor y en el lado del cliente.

Sólo puedes usar la librería `fs` en el código que se ejecutará en el servidor (dentro de las funciones `getInitialProps` o `getServerSideProps`). Cuando la plataforma a la que estás compilando es el navegador (lado del cliente), dicha librería no está disponible.